# ListView force app to close down

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a ListView to work, but I get a message on the screen that need to close down the app! I'm searching for error, but I can't find any! Perhaps it's inside the layout? I'm not sure about if I should have a ListView inside there or if this is created cdynamic? What am I doing wrong? I'm also going to use a onClick method, but I guess thats a miner problem in this case!? Preciate some help! Thanks!

```
public class Activity_3 extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

    // Get a cursor with all people
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_3, cursor, new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.contactItem });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/contactItem" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please try to post your DDMS error log. Open your logcat window and add a filter for your app. Then you can see the error. Also your layout xml seem to be incomplete. What IDE are you using?

Comment: where is ur adapterclass which extends SimpleCursorAdapter or baseadapter

Comment: if you are extending a List Activity then you dont need to put a listview in a layout.

Comment: OK, but I tested without a ListView in the layout, but still the same problem!?

Comment: Do I need a adapterclass also?

Comment: Can't you post the logcat ?

Comment: I thought this was easy to solve. The error contains info about "Invalid Column data1" Could that be a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you have added this permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

in manifest.xml

ok now this should be your activity

```
public class mainact extends Activity {

    ListView l;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactList);

        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

        // Get a cursor with all people

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
             String Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
             String Number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }
        startManagingCursor(phones);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.abc, phones, new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.contactItem });

        l.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

and xml should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/contactItem" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

or just suit you need but this is working code

Comment: That's why you need to post error log, we don't know why it crashes. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to use adapter that creates views where each view contains another ListView ?

Delete

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Normally you cannot put ListView in another ListView.

Comment: No I don't think so :) I just want to get a list of all contacts name and be able to pick name and numbers